# cannot set styling properties to undefined

Tags: javascript, html

here is my HTML :

```
<h1 id="test">Stand Out<h1>
```

what i want to do is to use the `slice()`method then to apply styling to a substring that i am selecting

here is my JS code

```
let out = document.getElementById('test').textContent.slice(6,9);
out.style.color = 'green';
```

**Now**, i don't know why i get the following ERROR

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

Comment: `out` is no longer a DOM element, its text

Comment: What do you believe that `out` will be? It's just the text `Out` and you can't set the style on just text. You'd need to wrap it in an element like a span

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `let` variable isn't a DOM object, it's simply a string. It doesn't have a `style` property that you can modify.

If this is simply a static page, I suggest wrapping the `Out` word into a separate `<span>` tag, then styling it accordingly:

`<h1 id="test">Stand <span id="test1">Out</span> </h1>`

and to style it green:

`document.getElementById("test1").style.color = "green";`

Comment: @SwilamMuhammad make sure to mark my answer if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let out = document.getElementById('inner');
out.style.color = 'green';
```

```html
<h1 id="test">Stand <span id='inner'> Out </span> </h1>
```